# CodeIgniter - Adding a default value to a form_dropdown

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm wondering if someone can help me out.  I have a form_dropdown which I'm filling with options from the database.  I want to add a default "Please Select" value at the top of the list, but can't figure out how to do it without adding that to the database.

My code is as follows:

```
function populatedropdown()
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$this->table_name.' WHERE active=1 ORDER BY brand');
    $dropdowns = $query->result();

    foreach($dropdowns as $dropdown) {
        $dropDownList[$dropdown->brand] = $dropdown->brand;
    }
    $finalDropDown = $dropDownList;

    return $finalDropDown;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another way to write it would be:

```
function populatedropdown()
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$this->table_name.' WHERE active=1 ORDER BY brand');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $dropdowns = $query->result();

        $dropDownList[''] = 'Please Select';    // default selection item
        foreach($dropdowns as $dropdown) {
            $dropDownList[$dropdown->brand] = $dropdown->brand;
        }

        return $dropDownList;
    } else {
        return false;       // return false if no items for dropdown
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use `''` as the key or `0` will be passed in the form value. i.e. `$dropDownList[''] = 'Please Select';` Unless you want that..?

Comment: @Madmartigan, thanks, done, also updated my answer to include row number check.

Comment: You don't need that as `result()` always returns an array. It's pointless. Returning false maybe isn't a good idea for a function that should return an array, an empty array might be more appropriate. So +1 and -1 :/

Answer (score 7):

Just add it to the array before you return it.

```
function populatedropdown()
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$this->table_name.' WHERE active=1 ORDER BY brand');
    $dropdowns = $query->result();

    foreach($dropdowns as $dropdown) {
        $dropDownList[$dropdown->brand] = $dropdown->brand;
    }
    $finalDropDown = array_merge(array('' => 'Please Select'), $dropDownList);

    return $finalDropDown;
}
```

Comment: Better yet, define `$dropDownList = array('' => 'Please Select');` first in case there's no DB results.  Plus the tiny tiny boost of not calling a function.

Comment: +1 - also, just use validation to keep the empty result out of the database and force a selection (if needed).

Comment: @BigJobbies: No prob.  This is how I do it on my site :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is also the possibility to change the form_helper.php and to add something like:

```
 $form .= '<option value =0 >...</option>';
```

to the form_dropdown func. However, I do not get it selected as default but the second entry in the form.

But the problem is that you change the core files which should not be down generally.